# How to make player move into next level in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

When my player reaches at the end of the map, I want it to enter to the next level. I've created the first level and it all works fine. All I want to do is that when player finishes 1st level I want to load another map on which it can move forward. But I'm not able to understand how to do it.

Here is piece of my code:

```
def runGame(theGame):

    theGame.clock.tick(FPS)

    # This function consists code for Events
    theGame.events()
    # This function consists code from enemy hit events
    theGame.hit_or_not()
    # This function consists code for player movements
    theGame.movements()
    # This function consists code for drawing the sprites over the screen
    theGame.redrawGameWindow()


def readyGame(run, gameOver):
    game = Game()

    while run:
        runGame(game)

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_x]:
            game = Game()
        elif keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            run = False
        pygame.event.pump()

        if gameOver:
            runGame(game)


readyGame(True, False)
```

Here is my whole code which is responsible for my 1st level please kindly check it - https://pastebin.com/zMFetAd6 (Game Class)

Do I have to create another class for 2nd level like I did for the 1st level?

Can anyone please help me out in this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

runGame can return a value as it is a function. Let's have it return `True` if a player completes the level. I'm assuming you already have a check for that in one of your other functions.

Your Game class can take arguments by adding them to its `__init__` method. Let's add a "level" argument and set the default to 0.

```
def __init__(self, level):
    if level == 0:
        # existing code for level 1 here
    elif level == 1:
        # code for level 2 here.

    # code that applies to all levels here.
```

Now all we have to do is create a new variable called level.

```
def readyGame(run, gameOver):
    level = 0
    game = Game(level)

    while run:
        if runGame(game) is True:
            print("Next level")
            level = level + 1
            game = Game(level)

        ...
```

From a pure code quality perspective, there are some things I might change about this implementation, but this will get you up and running.

In response to your comment:

```
class Game(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, level):  # add level parameter here
        super().__init__()
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        # This part stays the same for every level
        #   so I am cutting it out to save space

        if level == 1:
            self.hero = thePlayer(45, 625, 40, 40)

            self.enemy = # enemies for level 1
            self.platform = # platforms for level 1
        elif level == 2:
            self.hero = thePlayer(45, 625, 40, 40)

            self.enemy = # enemies for level 2
            self.platform = # platforms for level 2
        elif level == 3:
            # and so on

        self.facing = 0
        self.landed = True
        self.enterGame = pygame.image.load('startorclose.png')

        self.showMenu = pygame.image.load('MainMenu.png')
        self.stopScreen = False
        self.gameOver = False
```

This doesn't fit your code exactly because it seems like you'd have the the menu show up every time. But in short all you're adding is a new argument to `__init__` in the Game class and a `if` blocks here and there for the levels.

Your code has a lot of little issues so I'll leave you to hash it out and learn from the experience. Keep working and posting questions.

Comment: I didn't get it - how can i put my first level code inside of __init__ function - can you please show me how to do it using an example?